# AngularJs: How to get the attribute value of a attribute type directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive called my-directive which is of attribute type (restrict: 'A'). I use it as follows:

```
<input my-directive="mydvalue"/>
```

How do i get the "mydvalue" inside the directive?

```
app.directive("myDirective", function (){
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, el, attrs, controller) {
         //How do i get the mydvalue here.

      }

  };

});
```

Comment: Actually `attrs.myDirective`, but that's the idea.

Comment: Right, sorry for the mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `attrs.myDirective`

In attrs you have all the attributes of the element and a awesome ngModel too :) !